# Linphone iOS App crash during outgoing call, BackgroundTask

Tags: ios, swift, linphone

I build my own SIP app based on Linphone SDK.

When I make an outgoing call, then after 30 seconds of the call I get these messages:

```
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 7 ("Liblinphone cpu lock"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 10 ("belle-sip transaction(0x280e88410)"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
```

Then the App crash after 30 seconds or sometimes after up to max 4 minutes of having an outgoing call active. This crash also happens if my app is only ringing for more then 30 seconds when I try to make an outgoing call.

When the crash happens, then the app is NOT in background. The app is just in foreground during an outgoing all.

The app is build with Swift 5.0 and iOS target version 13.0

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: I have faced the same problem. got any solution?